# How to rollback transaction using LINQ-to-SQL in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, transactions

Here's my code:

```
TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope();
dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext()
// did some insert
var user = new User();
user.ID = 1;
user.Name = "Nick";

db.Users.Add(user);

db.SubmitChanges();
trans.Complete();
```

Now how do I rollback transaction if some error occurs while saving changes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `db.SubmitChanges();` ? What is definition of `dbDataContext`?

Comment: **Either** you're using Linq-to-SQL (an ORM built by the C# team as a proof-of-concept - runs only against SQL Server, uses `.dbml` model file) - **or then** you're using Entity Framework, which is another ORM, built by the ADO.NET team at Microsoft, which supports multiple databases and model- and code-based approaches - you cannot be using both at the same time. So which one is it??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can use transactions in entity framework. One using TransactionScope and another using database transaction.

For using database transaction, use the following code example:

```
using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
using (var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    try
    { 
        var user = new User(){ID = 1, Name = "Nick"};
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
    }
}
```

And here's an example of EF's TransactionScope:

```
using (TransactionScope tranScope = new TransactionScope())
using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
{
    try
    {
        var user = new User(){ID = 1, Name = "Nick"};
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        tranScope.Complete();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to call any Roll-Back method in the case of TransactionScope. If you don't call the Complete() method, the transaction does not get committed and gets rolled back automatically before being disposed.

Comment: thank you!! I'm new to entity framework.. This helps a lot.. :)

Comment: Does that code even compiles? Please check and correct.

Comment: @MKR I have provided the above code just for reference.

Comment: @chaosifier My doubt is on `SubmitChanges` function call. Am I missing something?